# How to choose item in SQL Lite?

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I create a `SQl Lite` table with Contact class and add some items to it:

```
string dbpath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "dbTest.db3");
var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
db.CreateTable<Contact>();
Contact contact1 = new Contact("ssS","555");
Contact contact2 = new Contact("ddd","444");
Contact contact3 = new Contact("ggg","111");
db.Insert(contact1);
db.Insert(contact2);
db.Insert(contact3);
```

and this is my contact class:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Contact(String name,string phone)
    {
        Name = name;
        PhoneNumber = phone;
    }
    public Contact()
    {

    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + "  " + PhoneNumber;
    }
}
```

now how I can receive contact2 from the table?

Comment: Using cursor you can get all your data.

Comment: Please give a complete code example. You must have a class and a method.

Comment: I did that guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In database, an entity should have a unique identifier and set it as primary key. In your case, probably it is best to add an ID for every contact (as some people do have identical name as well). To do so, you could modify your class to:

*Contact.cs*

```
public class Contact
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement] //use this so SQLite know this ContactId is the primary key of Contact entity
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

To retrieve the Contact by Primary Key (ContactId):

```
var contact = db.Table<Contact>().Where(x => x.ContactId == 1) //replace 1 with ID of contact you'd need to retrieve
```

Of course, you do not need to use `int` for the primary key's data type, you could use `string` or others matched with your needs.

To retrieve the Contact by Name:

```
var contact = db.Table<Contact>().Where(x => x.Name == "ToBeSearchedName") //replace "ToBeSearchedName" with string of the contact you'd need to retrieve
```

Hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var contact = db.Table<Contact>()
                .FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Name == "ddd");
```

Comment: thanks for reply.but what is id and how i can use it?

Comment: You are welcome. Could you please post also the defintion of `Contact` class in your question? Thanks

Comment: sure,i added contact class to question

Comment: Please see my update and let me know.           Thanks

Comment: @Mehrdad I have updated my answer. Please try the code snippet I have there and let me know if it's ok. Thanks

Comment: I saw that.but i don't know how it works.im new to sql lite.may please give me a source to read about that?

Comment: I would check to find a source. However, does this solve your problem? You have posted some code, which indicates how you create the table and how you insert data to it. Right after this you could try to execute the code that is included in the answer above and check if it it does what you want. Have you tried this?

Comment: There isn't any property called Id? So how did you get this error message?

Comment: i did not defined id and the error is this:does not contain a definition for id and no extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type "App.Contact"could be found.